# Ошибка java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, gradle, mock

При запуске тестов с MockMvc получаю ошибку: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet, как ее исправить?

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [Application.class])
@WebAppConfiguration
class MyTest extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac

    private MockMvc mockMvc

    def setup() {
            mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(wac)
            .build()
    }

    def "my test"() {
            when:
            def result = mockMvc.perform(get("/main"))

        then:
            result.andExpect(status().isOk())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исключение `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` возникает, как правило, когда у Вас во время компиляции класс есть в classpath, а во время выполнения его нет. Решается добавлением корректных зависимостей в classpath запускаемого приложения.